# Displaying arrayList to JList annoying bug Java

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlist

I've got this simple little strange bug that when I want to show an arrayList in the JList it shows me like this:

```
2, 123, Wooden chairs 40.0
2, 123, Wooden chairs 40.02, 123, Wooden chairs 40.0...
2, 123, Wooden chairs 40.02, 123, Wooden chairs 40.0...
```

The first line is okay, but after the first line it keeps repeating, I've tried adding the `\n` but still does not work, but when checking the arrayList in the console everything is okay. Can somebody look at the code and explain to me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it. Here is the code:

```
private void buildList(ArrayList<Product> basketList)
{   
    String[] blist = new String[basketList.size()];
    int index = 0;
    String listString = "";
    for(Product prodObj : basketList)
    {
        listString += prodObj;
        blist[index] = listString;
        index++;
    }
    list.setListData(blist);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `listString += prodObj;` What do you think this does?

Comment: your basketList is two dimensional, should be used for JTable (or JTree:-), but nor for JList --> single column, rest is in Oracle tutorial - How to use List